# JQuery .on('keydown',...) not triggering on new elements

Tags: jquery

I looked through some related questions, but none helped me figure out my problem.

I have my own dynamic data grid form built from scratch, where rows of data and field columns can be added/removed etc. I'm trying to improve the usability so that pressing the enter key will create a new field column and give focus to it. Here's the code that does this so far:

```
$('#data_fields').on('keydown','._field',function(e){
    if(e.which==13)
    {
        $('#addfield').click();
        var o=$(this).parent().parent();
        var l=$(o).children().length-2;
        var f=$(o).find("td:eq("+l+")").find("._field");
        $(f).focus();
    }
});
```

`#addfield` is a button which adds the field column when clicked.

`._field` is an input box where the name of the field is written.

`#data_fields` is a tr containing cells with `._field` input boxes in them.

However, the `._field` input boxes in the new columns do not have the special superelement keydown ability. Whats more, if I change the `('#data_fields')` selector for `.on()` to `(document)`, it doesn't even give current elements the keydown callback.

Here's the HTML, sorry that its a bit messy but I use templates in PHP and stuff:

```
<thead id="doc_fields">
  <tr id="delrow">
  <tr id="data_fields">
    <td style="padding:2px"><input class="_field" type="text" onkeyup="sync_doc_table();" onchange="sync_doc_table();" style="width:90%" value="" name="Fields[]"></td>
    <td style="padding:2px"><input class="_field" type="text" onkeyup="sync_doc_table();" onchange="sync_doc_table();" style="width:90%" value="b" name="Fields[]"></td>
    <td style="padding:2px"><input type="text" style="width:90%" value="" name="Fields[]" onchange="sync_doc_table();"></td>
    <td style="padding:2px"><input type="text" style="width:90%" value="" name="Fields[]" onchange="sync_doc_table();"></td>
    <td id="addcol" class="midi" style="width:25px" rowspan="3">
      <a id="addfield" onclick="inscol('#addcol','<td style=\'padding:2px\'><input onchange=\'sync_doc_table();\' type=\'text\' name=\'Fields[]\' value=\'\' style=\'width:90%\' /></td>');addcol('#typerow','<td><select name=\'Type[]\' style=\'width:91%\'><option value=\'integer\'>integer</option><option value=\'double\'>double</option><option value=\'string\' selected=\'selected\'>string</option></select></td>');addcol('#delrow','<td class=\'center _delly\'><a href=\'#\' onclick=\'del_doc_field($(this).parent());return false;\'><img src=\'/images/icons/x.png\' alt=\'[Del]\' /></a></td>');$('._colsp').attr('colspan', $('#addrow').attr('colspan') + 1);$('<td><input type=\'text\' name=\'Data[][]\' value=\'\' style=\'width:90%\' /></td>').insertBefore('.datarow ._delly');return false;" href="#">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="typerow">
</thead>
```

Comment: you should really use .trigger('click') rather than .click().

Comment: Try posting some markup or better yet create a fiddle example, that should make understanding this question easier.

Comment: What does this mean: "new rows do not have the special superelement keydown ability"? Do you mean new columns? Is the problem that you can add one column, but when you keydown in that column the event isn't fired?

Comment: @PatrickM Yes, more specifically, the input boxes within the new columns dont fire the keydown event. I've updated the question with HTML code.

Comment: In fact, seeing the neat Firebug version of the HTML helped me notice the problem. The script that adds the new columns doesn't apply the '_field' class needed by the selector. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also have the same problem. `$('body').on('keydown', '.specific_element', function(e) { console.log($(this)); });` is never triggered (old or new elements!)…

Comment: Perhaps you should accept the answer below so that people visiting the page find the mistake without having to read all comments?

Comment: well it was added WAYY after the fact, but since you caught my attention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From What I can tell it's because your input class that's being appended doesn't have a `_field` class in it.